# Notice: Undefined variable: count line 53

Tags: php

```
 $count = 0;

$interpreter->addObserver(function(array $row) use (&$temperature) {
   $count+=1;

   if ($count < 3)  <----- not liking this 
   {

       return;

   }
    $temperature[] = array(
        'column1' => $row[16],
        'column2'  => $row[18],
    );
});
```

I am assuming it is a scope issue and I am unable to access the count from outside however I do need to count the rows in loop....thoughts?

Comment: I'm surprised you got this right for `$temperature` but not `$count`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could refer to the global by adding the following as the first line of your function:

```
global $count;
```

However, does it need to be global? You might create a static variable, which will retain its value between your method calls:

```
static $count = 0;
```

Comment: Since he's using an anonymous function `use ($count)` would be much better than `global`.

Comment: @deceze I haven't used [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) with PHP, but shouldn't $count be passed by reference for this example? `use (&$count, &$temperature)`

Comment: Yes, sure, it'd be a reference in this case.